# nuget.config file in asp.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I make available the package bellow for me to use in project.json:

https://myget.org/feed/aspnetvnext/package/nuget/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server

I know that I need to change the NuGet.config file, but I don´t know how.

Obs: I´m not using Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line on your dependecies inside project.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server" : "0.2.0-alpha1-21444"
}
```

Just be sure to choose the correct version for the assembly, VS has intellisense on the packages.

Comment: But I get this error: error: Unable to resolve 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Server (>= 0.2.0-alpha1-21444)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.0'.

Comment: It's because this assembly only works with .NETFramework 4.5.1 and .NETStandard 1.6. Which framework are you using?

Comment: I´m using .net core 1.0

Comment: Can you post your project.json?